# WebdriverIO - How to run .bat script using WebDriverIO

Tags: webdriver-io

Is there a possibility to run .bat file (script) using WebdriverIO, preferable into before hook, located into WDIO.conf file?

```
before: function () {
        console.log("this is before");
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible you just need to import `execFileSync` and `join` methods and then you can run it like that:

```
const { execFileSync } = require('child_process');
const { join } = require('path');

before: function () {
   execFileSync(join(__dirname, './script.bat'));
}
```

Read more about `execFileSync` method [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfilesync_file_args_options)